# How to extract alarm ringtone files from my phone?

Tags: system, files, alarm

I have an OPPO R11 and I really like one of the default alarm sounds, so I was wondering how I could extract the sound file from the Android system to save it. I've tried downloading ES File Explorer, and so far the only ringtone and notification sounds that I've found are for Google hangouts only. I've searched it pretty extensively but still haven't found where all the system tones are stored.

Comment: It isn't rooted, is it ?

Comment: Yes, it isn't rooted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you won't be able to read system directory on your phone without root permissions which also means that you won't be able get ringtones as it requires atleast read permission on system partition